# Contrário de appendHTML - como fazer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

Tenho uma *label* no formulário do meu site que adiciona à uma `div` (no caso do exemplo, a `id` dessa `div` é **`grupoExt`**) um conteúdo HTML. Eis o código:

```
var numeroFE = 2;
$("#addFE").click(function(){
    var html3  = "<div class='BoxForm1'>";
        html3 += "<div class='inputMGM'><input name='nomeFE"+numeroFE+"' id='' class='validate[required]' title=''></input></div></div>";
        html3 += "<div class='BoxForm2'>";
        html3 += "<div class='inputMGM'><input name='empresaFE"+numeroFE+"' id='' class='validate[required]' title=''></input></div></div>";
    $('#grupoExt').append(html3);
    document.getElementById('grupoExt_text').value=numeroFE;
    numeroFE++;
});
```

Gostaria de saber se é possível fazer o contrário. Ou seja, usar de código JavaScript pra remover este código adicionado à `div` **`grupoExt`**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Podes fazer só:

```
document.getElementById('grupoExt').innerHTML = '';
```

Que com jQuery seria:

```
$('#grupoExt').html('');
```

Com jQuery Também tens as funções:

[remove()](https://api.jquery.com/remove/):

```
$('#grupoExt *').remove();
```

[empty()](https://api.jquery.com/empty/):

```
$('#grupoExt').empty();
```

Cujo  resultado final dos dois acima é o mesmo (apesar de retornarem coisas diferentes).